# JavaScript "use strict" inconsistently working in Chrome snippets / DevTools Sources panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, use-strict

I am currently taking a Udemy course on "Advanced" Javascript concepts (https://www.udemy.com/course/javascript-advanced/), and the first lesson goes over the "use strict" command and its functionality. The course uses Chrome's Sources panel to write code in snippets and observe expected results.

For some reason I am having inconsistent success with the "use strict" command when following along with the video.

Example:
The course writes the following code as an example of when "use strict" will throw an error on screen to showcase that an undefined variable is present..

```js
  "use strict";
  //
  var theVal = 0;
  //
  thVal = 1;
  //
  if (theVal > 0) {
      console.log("Hello!");
  }
```

In the video, an error is throw - "Uncaught ReferenceError: thVal is not defined" - and a red "x" appears on line 5 of the snippet to highlight where the error was thrown. However, for some reason I am not seeing that error.

The weird thing is that I can change the incorrectly stated variable to anything else - "thValue", "theVol", etc. - and the error message and "x" will appear. Is there something that I am missing here? I make sure to save the snippet before running but for some reason I cannot follow along with the video exactly as shown and it's simply bugging me as to why this is happening specifically when using "thVal".

Comment: `for some reason I am not seeing that error`. I've updated your post and now you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
   "use strict";
    
var theVal = 0;
    
theVal = 1;
   
if (theVal > 0) {
   console.log("Hello!");
}
```

The purpose of `"use strict"` is to indicate that the code should be executed in "strict mode". With strict mode, you can not use undeclared variables. For example `thVal = 1;` is undeclared. You can find the working code above.

Comment: I understand that the code I posted is incorrect and will (should) throw an error. The error in my code is what I'm trying to get my console to show to me, but it doesn't do so when I specifically use (incorrectly non-declared variable) "thVal" and expect to see an error due to being in strict mode. I may not have explained well but I'm following along with a video tutorial that is showcasing the use-case of "use strict" and highlighting the benefit of being able to quickly catch syntax errors in large blocks of code.

Comment: Explaining a bit more.. if line 5 were
        5. "thyVal" = 1;
I will correctly see an error on my screen and the if statement will not execute. If line 5 were 
        5. "theVal" = 1;
The if loop will run as expected, no errors. However, if I try to have line 5 specifically be
        5. "thVal" = 1;
The if statement will not execute, but more specifically, the error will also not show up on my screen - as one would expect to take advantage of strict mode to catch that sort of error.

Comment: can you explain me in detail with code as to what you did not understand

Comment: Figured it out! Someone on reddit was able to assist.

In the course I am following along with, the instructor is first using my above code without "use strict" and failing to print hello. In that moment thVal variable is being declared and is defined as long as the window is open.

After that, he is adding "use strict", but before executing the command he is refreshing the page. By refreshing the page, he is clearing the previously declared variables.

So my issue was not refreshing the page to clear out the "thVal" declaration w/o "use strict", so now I correctly see an error message.